How to Receive JSON Data and File Upload Together in FastAPI
I'm working on a FastAPI project where I need to receive both JSON data and a file upload in the same request. Specifically, I need to pass an array of integers within the JSON data while also uploading a file. Here is what my request body looks like:

title (string)
description (string)
comments (string)
due_date (date)
priority (string)
assigned_to (array of integers)
file (file upload)

I'm having trouble getting FastAPI to accept this type of mixed data in a single request. Here is my current approach:
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
import datetime

app = FastAPI()

class TaskCreate(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    comments: str
    due_date: datetime.date
    priority: str
    assigned_to: List[int]

@app.post("/tasks/")
async def create_task(
    title: str = Form(...),
    description: str = Form(...),
    comments: str = Form(...),
    due_date: datetime.date = Form(...),
    priority: str = Form(...),
    assigned_to: List[int] = Form(...),
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    return {"title": title, "description": description, "comments": comments, "due_date": due_date, "priority": priority, "assigned_to": assigned_to, "file_name": file.filename}


The assigned_to parameter does not seem to accept an array of integers when sent with Form(...). FastAPI throws an error because it does not support lists in form data.
I need a way to send both JSON data (including an array of integers) and a file in the same request and have FastAPI handle it correctly. What is the best approach to achieve this in FastAPI?
